# AnyLogic parameter variation experiment with parameter arrays

Tags: arrays, parameters, anylogic

My simulation model has three main planning parameters, that is unique for each unique item. I want to do a parameter variation in AnyLogic to find the optimal values for the parameters.

In this model there can be many items, therefore I created parameters with the type set to 'other' and created a new array of integers as `new int[]{1,1,1,1,1,1}`, which represents the unique planning parameter for each item. This solution gives no issues during normal simulation runs.

However, the arrays do not seem to work in a parameter variation experiment. Because there are many parameters I cannot hardcode every parameter. Is it possible to use a parameter array in the parameter variation experiment as explained above?

Comment: yep, that doesn't work... to solve this you would need to use custom experiment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if you define a matrix in your experiment that defines how to vary experiments. For example below, `matrixOfCombinations` would be a collection of matrices and you access it by the index of the iteration (as an example).

This is fairly advanced, though, and you have to be careful to manage parallel executions correctly. Best start with a much simpler setup and nudge yourself towards the final solution

[image]